# habilitar o deshahilitar un boton en swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Tengo varios botones dentro de un view controller, pero hay uno de ellos que quiero que este deshabilitado si en un `textfield` no hay ningún valor escrito.

Si se escribe algun valor se debe volver a habilitar.

```
import UIKit

class AreaOfAnIsoscelesTriangleViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var texfieldA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textfieldB: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var label3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var label4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var label5: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var label6: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var label7: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        textfieldB.resignFirstResponder()
        texfieldA.resignFirstResponder()


        let numbersquareA = Double(texfieldA.text!)!
        let resultSquareA = pow(numbersquareA, 2)

        let numbersquare  = Double(textfieldB.text!)!
        let resultSquare = pow(numbersquare, 2)

        let variableA = Double(texfieldA.text!)!
        let variableB = Double(textfieldB.text!)!


        label1.text = "b * √a^2 - b^2 /4 /2"
        label2.text = "\(variableB) * √\(variableA)^2 - \(variableB)^2 /4 /2"
        label3.text = "\(variableB) * √\(resultSquareA) - \(resultSquare) /4 /2"

        let operation1 = resultSquare / 4
        let operation2 = resultSquareA - operation1

        label4.text = "\(variableB) * √\(resultSquareA) - \(operation1)  /2"
        label5.text = "\(variableB) * √\(operation2)/2"

        let operation3 =  sqrt(operation2)
        let operation3final = String(format: "%.2f", operation3)

        label5.text = "\(variableB) * \(operation3final)/2"

        let operation3intValue = Double(operation3final)

        let operation4 = variableB * operation3intValue!
        let operation5 = operation4/2



        label6.text = "\(operation4)/2"
        label7.text = "\(operation5)"


    }





    @IBAction func bottonstep(_ sender: UIButton) {



        let variableA = Double(texfieldA.text!)!
        let variableB = Double(textfieldB.text!)!

        let numbersquareA = Double(texfieldA.text!)!

        let numbersquare  = Double(textfieldB.text!)!
        let resultSquareA = pow(numbersquareA, 2)
        let resultSquare = pow(numbersquare, 2)


        let alertControler : UIAlertController = UIAlertController (title: "The steps to follow are those :", message: "Step 1 - (b * √a^2 - b^2 /4 /2).Replace the variable of the equation with its corresponding values in this case would be \(variableB) * √\(variableA)^2 - \(variableB)^2 /4 /2 \n Step 2: To raise numbers according to their exponents \(variableB) * √\(resultSquareA) - \(resultSquare) /4 /2" , preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let okAction :UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: nil)

        alertControler.addAction(okAction)

        present(alertControler , animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

El boton que necesito que se encuentre deshabilitado si no se ha introducido un valor en el campo de texto es `bottonstep`.

Como seria el metodo ? tendría que ponerlo como outlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como bien dices tienes que crear un outlet para el botón si quieres acceder a él desde código.
La función sería algo así:

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
        if texField.text?.isEmpty{
            boton.isEnabled = false
        }else{
            boton.isEnabled = true
        }
}
```

Y en el viewDidLoad le dices al textField correspondiente que llame a la función:

```
comentarioTF.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

Si el textField va a estar vacío al empezar, deja el botón deshabilitado en viewDidLoad o desde el apartado Accessibility en el Identity Inspector

Si quieres que más de un textField hagan la llamada pero hagan cosas distintas asigna distintos tags y compruébalos en la función

Comment: inicie el boton dehabilitado y lo mande a habilitar cuando se pulsa el boton proncipal

Answer (score 2):

primero tienes que agregar el protocolo **UITextFieldDelegate** y dentro de la función:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{
  if yourTextfield == textField{
     buttonToDisable.isEnabled = (string != "" && textField.text != "")
  }
  return true

}
```

Te recomiendo que la adopción del protocolo la hagas en una extension de tu ViewController.